# Relation between ExtJS Direct and DirectJNgine

Tags: javascript, extjs

Am new to `ExtJS Direct` and `DirectJNgine`. The relation between them confuses me. I cannot get the overview picture.

What I know is:
`ExtJS` is a `JavaScript` framework focusing on UI design. It supplies plethora `APIs` for programmers. I can call these APIs without bitter.

From the official site:

> **Ext Direct** is a platform and language agnostic technology to remote server-side methods to the client-side. Ext Direct allows for **seamless communication** between the client-side of an Ext JS application and all popular server platforms.

My think is: ExtJS Direct is also a subset of the APIs supplied the ExtJS team for us to use. These APIs can facilitate our work on calling server side method. But I want to dig into a little bit.

1. Server side method can be any language method, like JAVA C++ PHP etc. Direct APIs handle all possibilities to support different server side language methods?

From the official site:

> **DirectJNgine** (or DJN, for short), is a Java based implementation of the Ext Direct API for ExtJs.
>   ExtJs is probably one of the most powerful and attractive UIs for web-based applications, as can be seen here, as well as in many other examples. DirectJNgine makes it much easier to use the full power of Java business classes with such a powerful front-end, making Java methods directly callable from the client.

1. Since ExtJS Direct is already implemented the APIs for seamless remote method invoking. Why DirectJNgine need to implement these ExtJS Direct APIs? What does "a java based implementation of the Ext Direct API for ExtJs" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd add ***server-side*** to the definition `DirectJNgine`:

> **DirectJNgine** is an Open Source library that provides a Java-based implementation of the ***server-side*** *Ext Direct* API.

`Ext Direct` is a javascript framework and resides on client and let's you call any server API. The call is made *via HTTP - that's why it's not dependent on the server language*. You formulate a HTTP request, not a Java/PHP/any other request.

Server API handles the HTTP request and can be implemented in Java, C++, PHP, .Net etc. One of the Java implementations is `DirectJNgine`. It runs on server and responses to `Ext Direct` calls.

In your project you can use both `Ext Direct` and `DirectJNgine` for communication between client and server. *They don't overlap, they cooperate with each other on the opposite sides of the network.*

And you'd use some framework for the presentation layer (ExtJS maybe) and some framework for server business/storage/other layers (to make use of `DirectJNgine` it would be a Java framework).

Comment: Your explanation is really clear and concise. I accept it. By the way, the official ExtJS Direct example's server side is PHP, not DirectJNgine. Can I say that?

Comment: Yes, they use PHP in their examples, but there is also a [list of server side stacks](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?67992-Ext.Direct-Server-side-Stacks).

Comment: Fine. Seemingly I got the basic overview. Why we call a server side implementation a "stack"?

Comment: We call [Solution stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) any set of systems which cooperate together to deliver the desired functionality. Here PHP is a server side subsystem of the whole stack.

Answer (score 0):

Extjs needs to know the URL, the methods and the parameter count for the possible actions and this is provided by for example DirectJNgine.

The API also takes care of messaging between ExtJS and JAVA , i.e. converting incoming JSON objects to JAVA methods (Json with method names and parameters is passed to JAVA methods, their can be multiple actions in one call). And passing back the result from the JAVA methods in JSON format.

Comment: DirectJNgine implements the same set of APIs as ExtJS Direct API? The only difference is the language used for implementation?

Comment: The API is only at the server side( c#, java, PHP) so ExtJs (the client side) doesn't have an API. The server side APIs are to provide direct access from the client side to the server side. ExtJs just uses this API to generate JS methods and other bindings.

Comment: A nice summary of the functionality can be found here: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect/

Comment: Thx very much. Could you explain the relation of ExtJS Direct API and DirectJNgine API? "The API is only at the server side", here, what API do you refer to? Is it DirectJNgine API?

Could you kindly help me explain the two question in my post? I am really confused by these new terms like ExtJS API, ExtJS Direct API, and DirectJNgine API. What are their purpose and how they coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging into extdirectspring when I realised some strange stuff was going on and wanted to know why.  Effectively what extdirect does is provide a description of the server side methods to the client in the form of json (+ possibly through other mediums).

On the client side you end up with objects built from this json that know how to call the server code.  In the java (extdirectspring) implementation this creates a static variable in your program's namespace for each of the java classes decorated with the 'ExtDirectMethod' attribute.  This variable seems to always be the class name with the first letter lowercased.  I had a bit of a dig and this appears to be by coincidence - the name comes from the bean name in spring and is not defined by extdirectspring.

In extdirectspring the setup works through the ether (through the servlet + spring) (have yet to bottom out exactly how this works) and it is predefined to respond to requests for api.js (among other things).  This then returns the configuration object which is assigned to a static variable in the ext namespace.  By default this variable is called REMOTING_API.

To get the client side stuff to know about what the server has to offer you need to put in a call like:

```
Ext.direct.Manager.addProvider(Ext.app.REMOTING_API);
```

after extjs has fired up.